# getting "Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier..." while converting oracle query to big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to convert a oracle query to a plain SQL query. In oracle the join condition will be done this way:

```
Select col1,col2,col3 
from TABLE1,TABLE2
 WHERE TABLE1.COL IN TABLE2.COL2
```

When I'm converting the above code to a plain SQL query:

```
Select col1,col2,col3
from TABLE1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE2
     ON TABLE1.COL IN TABLE2.COL2
```

I'm getting `Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier "TABLE2"`

Comment: Does that work in Oracle?  What is the data type of `col2`?

Comment: The first query will definitely **not** work on Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a `=` and not IN   ..
IN clause require ()

```
  Select col1,col2,col3 
  from TABLE1 
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.COL = TABLE2.COL2
```

Comment: is it valid? because in oracle they have mentioned as 'IN' not '='. so IN and = are same?

Comment: IN require a list of elements inside  ()  .. if you have not a list but only a value you need a single operator as =  ... try

Answer (score 0):

If `col2` is an array, you can use:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM TABLE2 t2 CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(t2.col2) as col2_element JOIN
     TABLE1 t1
     ON t1.COL = col2_element;
```