# Unexpected error when trying to parse string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table in PostgreSQL:

`Table_T`:

| id | body |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bla bla bla Call ID: xxx Interaction ID: vvv bla bla |
| 2 | bla bla bla Call ID: zzz Interaction ID: ooo bla bla |

This is the output I am expecting:

| id | Call_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx |
| 2 | zzz |

This the code I am using:

```
SELECT id
     , substring(body from position('Call ID:' in body)+8 for position('Interaction ID:' in body)- position('Call ID:' in body)+8)
FROM Table_T
```

I get this error:

> Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier at

Some documentation I reviewed:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html
- https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/position-function.php
- [getting "Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier..." while converting oracle query to big query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494352/getting-syntax-error-expected-or-keyword-unnest-but-got-identifier-whi)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems unrelated. The expression works for me. Except that you seem to have your calculation wrong. And it can be done much simpler with [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) and a regular expression:

```sql
SELECT id
     , substring(body FROM position('Call ID:' in body) + 9 FOR position('Interaction ID:' in body) - position('Call ID:' in body) - 10) AS proper
     , substring(body, 'Call ID: (.*) Interaction ID:') AS better
FROM   table_t;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/46fwuZ-b)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution didnt cross my mind to use the regex in the substring formula. Sorry for the wrong math

Comment: @PhilC. If that answers your question properly, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_match`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

```
select id, (regexp_match(body, '(?<=ID\:\s)\w+'))[1] Call_id from Table_T
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l9i9yrYj).

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution it looks super awesome, what does this (regex_match)[#] mean?

Comment: @PhilC. `(regex_match)[#]` is accessing the first element in the set of matches that is being produced by `regexp_match`.